# Why does Kernels[] produce this error?

Tags: warning-messages

Most of times, on my PC, when `Kernel[]` is launched for the first time, produces this error:

[image]

Executed again returns `{}`.

Is it a clue of malfunctioning or is, for reason I'm unaware of, the way it is supposed to work ?

Seen on a machine running an Intel Q9400 quad core CPU.

#### Addendum

Same as above for

```
report= Benchmark[];
```

but the computation goes forward, nevertheless.

Comment: Version? What if you do the evaluation in a regular notebook instead of the documentation?

Comment: Thanks for replying ! Version is 8.0.1.0. In a regular notebook it happens the same.

Comment: I don't see it in my version of 8.0.1, so I'm not sure what would cause this.